# What's the best way to append multiple divs and images and other tags with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have some big outter div called `container` and I want to append a bunch of data that has this format:

```
<div class="row faces-row valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col s3"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/face-panel/image-5.png"/></div>
  <div class="col s3">Happy Face</div>
  <div class="col s2 center-align">A</div>
  <div class="col s2 center align">A</div>
  <div class="col s2 center align">A</div>
</div>
```

I mean I can just copy paste that entire chunk and put it as a string inside

`$("#container").append(very_long_string);` but clearly there is a much better way, and was wondering if you guys had some insight to provide me :) ?

I could do this, but I wish there's a cleaner way:

```
$('#container').append(
  '<div class="row face-row valign-wrapper">' + 
  '<div class="col s3"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/face-panel/face-5.png"/></div>' +
  '<div class="col s3">HAPPY FACE</div>' + 
  '<div class="col s2 center-align">A</div>' + 
  '<div class="col s2 center align">A</div>' + 
  '<div class="col s2 center align">A</div>' + 
  '</div>'
);
```

Comment: Use the string as you have or use Ajax to load a template file or have a pre-existing section in your page already that is hidden that you can clone.

Comment: if text inside is not going to change (i.e they are static)  loading a template file through Ajax is good option like most comic website does
 but if you require to change those text or do some dynaimc changes with JS, javascript template engine is good https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript_templates

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamically add content into div container.you can use template engine as well.according to the your requirement.you can use javascript template engine [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

create a html page with your content.you also can add dynamically content as well.It is not you requirement.but we can do this as well.

```
$.get('../path-to-template/template.html', function (template) {
        renderdContent = Mustache.render(template,options);
});
```

Comment: ah cool this is interesting, but I'm actually making a function that takes 3 parameters, and then an array with about 10 different flags, which would alter what is shown in between the appended divs. I just left them as specifics to make things easier for now.

Answer (score 0):

To your cose be fast, save your HTML into string or array, add all content and on final end just do append.

Is not good to have to many append because page will be overkilled if you need to append huge HTML many times.

Comment: but my example already has a long string, separated with `+`,  and a single append. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way?

Comment: Your example is totaly ok but cleaner way is to each line of html put in string or array. I use array and in append just do join. But also your way is totaly ok if you append only once or twice something.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var longStr = '\
  <div class="row face-row valign-wrapper"> \ 
      <div class="col s3"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/face-panel/face-5.png"/></div> \
      <div class="col s3">HAPPY FACE</div> \ 
      <div class="col s2 center-align">A</div> \ 
      <div class="col s2 center align">A</div> \ 
      <div class="col s2 center align">A</div> \ 
  </div> \
';

$('#container').append(longStr);
```